# Doe HERE provide a way to access the UK's Ordnance Survey Maps?

Tags: maps, here-api

Does HERE provide a way to access the UK's Ordnance Survey Maps?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we do not have any way to access the UK's Ordnance Survey Maps but we provide other features to enrich your map. Kindly refer to the below link.

Link: https://developer.here.com/products/platform/data